# How can i know who voted without signing them into my app..?

Tags: javascript, express, mongoose

I want to create an website where people can create their own polls like for e.g. instagram polls but the real deal is how can i know who voted and avoid them from voting > 1 time without signing them in..?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), visit the [Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help) and read up about [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) a good question.  So my first question is: What have you tried yourself?

Answer (score 0):

The best you can if you don't want any kind of user authentication, it's using cookies wich never expires. But the customer can switch the browser, or clean his cookies and vote again